# Regex group matches with space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have simple problem with regex, but I haven't idea for resolve them. I have string (in grey this is a label):

> `cccc`:ddddd `bbbb`:fgggg `aaa aa`:ddd ddd `cccc`:ggggggg

and regex

```
/(aaa aa|bbbb|cccc)+:([\sa-zA-Z]*)(?:$|\s)/ig
```

https://regex101.com/r/mR3vK5/1

After parsing string 'label' `aaa aa` is ignoring, because have space and is taken to second match. I want to do first match labels (with white space or not), colon and anything (with spaces) after insert into second match to next 'label' or end line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know all the keys you may use them inside the positive lookahead and match the values with lazy dot:

```
/(aaa aa|bbbb|cccc):(.*?)(?=$|\s+(?:aaa aa|bbbb|cccc))/gi
```

See the JS demo:

```js
var block = "aaa aa|bbbb|cccc";
var rx = RegExp("(" + block + "):(.*?)(?=$|\\s+(?:" + block + "))", "ig");
var s = "cccc:ddddd bbbb:fgggg aaa aa:ddd ddd cccc:ggggggg";
while ((m = rx.exec(s)) !== null) {
    document.body.innerHTML += m[1] + ": " + m[2] + "<br/>";
}
```

**Pattern explanation**:

- `(aaa aa|bbbb|cccc)` - either of `aaa aa` or `bbbb` or `cccc`
- `:`  - a literal colon
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 matching 0+ any chararacter other than a newline as few as possible up to the first...
- `(?=$|\s+(?:aaa aa|bbbb|cccc))` - (a positive lookahead that limits the `.*?` matching)

  - `$` - ... end of string
  - `|` - or...
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces followed with...

    - `(?:aaa aa|bbbb|cccc)` - any of the three alternatives (inside a non-capturing group used for grouping only, not capturing)

Comment: This is good, I think that hasn't simpler solution. But I never understand, what mean (`?=`$|\s+

Answer (score 0):

Well so this will do what you want

`/(aaa aa|bbbb|cccc)+:(\s*[a-zA-Z]*)(?:$|\s)/ig`

But, it is highly contrived, given the question.

Comment: But in link to regex101, I forgot about space between `ddd ddd`

Comment: Ahh well the positive lookahead solution is superior anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get just the labels (even if the key has a space), here's something I quickly typed up:  https://regex101.com/r/jJ9iI1/3

```
(?:^|\s)([^:]+):
```

It starts off with a `^` or `\s` (beginning or space character).  Then it simply captures every character (except the colon) leading up to a colon.

...make sure the `g` for global is turned on

Comment: But I need pair: label and value in result

Comment: Not sure I completely understand.  Capturing the values is the same thing just put the colon first.  By the way I just noticed that my original solution should have a non-capturing or to start....(?:^|\s)([^:]+):

Comment: I think that Your solution need develop https://regex101.com/r/jJ9iI1/4 but thanks for inspiration